# Find the basis for the intersection of two subspaces in infinite-dimensional vector spaces

Tags: reference-request, vector-spaces

For an infinite-dimensional vector space *U*, and two subspaces *W* and *V*, we assume at least one of the two subspaces (*W* and *V*) is also infinite-dimensional.

How can I find the basis for the intersection of *W* and *V*?

EDIT (*Modification of the question as follows*):

Given an explicit basis of infinite-dimensional vector space *U*

{$u_n \in U$ | $n \in N$}

and the explicit basis of *W* and *V*

{$w_m \in W$ | $m \in N$} and
{$v_l \in V$ | $l \in N$},

where N = {1,  2, 3, ...},

what algorithm or procedure that I can use to:

(1) determine whether the intersection of *W* and *V* is empty, or not; and

(2) find an explicit basis for the intersection subspace, if it is not empty.

if these cannot always be achieved, what are the necessary and/or sufficient conditions for achieving the above results?

If someone could point me to the references on this topic, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: You can't even find a basis for an infinite-dimensional vector space, e.g., the vector space of all power series, without invoking the axiom of choice, so it's not clear to me what you would consider to be a success in finding a basis for an intersection of infinite-dimensional subspaces. Anyway, a lot is going to depend on just what $V$ and $W$ are, and how they are given. [That's true, even if everything is finite-dimensional]

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I realized that my original question was too "soft" and modified (hopefully improved) it to make it more solid. Could you point me to the available references (book or paper) that had tackled this problem, or closely related topics? Thanks!

Comment: The question is much better now. I hope someone can contribute to an answer. I suspect that even the determination of whether the intersection is non-empty is going to require further conditions.